# U-substitution for integral

Tags: integration

$$\int \frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}\,\,\mathbb{d}x$$

This integral is really confusing me.

Can I use a u-substitution and write that $u=x^2+y^2$, and $\mathbb{d}u=2x\mathbb{d}x$?

$$\int\frac{1}{u}\mathbb{d}u=\ln|u|+c=\ln|x^2+y^2|+c$$

Is that correct? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes. That's correct. Also, you don't need to put absolute sign in the final answer as $\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 $, $x^2+y^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: $$\int \frac{f'}{f} = \ln(f)$$